# Can I wire a three phase, nine wire dual voltage motor for single phase 220V?

Tags: transformer, three-phase, single-phase

I have a 5hp nine wire, three phase dual voltage (low / high) motor and I need it to run on 220V single phase for an air compressor.

Please help - I've had several "electricians" say they can do it but none have.

Comment: It is possible to run a 3 phase motor with a single phase supply using a capacitor (sometimes 2). However, power will be less. You give us no details to work with.

Comment: Can your "220 V" supply in excess of 4 kW/5 kVA? There seem to be two different internal connections with 9-wire motors: a) Y with each limb split, star point is not a terminal b) Δ style: 3 separate Vs. Please tell which, and/or show an image of the "boilerplate".

Comment: Thank you for your response I will take a picture of the plate on motor in a few minutes

Answer (score 1):

The winding configuration of a three-phase, nine-wire, dual-voltage motor is as follows:

[image]

T1, T2 & T3 are the three-phase supply terminals.

Connections for the lower and higher supply voltages are as shown below.

[image]

[image]

It's a star-connected motor at both the voltages. The higher voltage is generally double the lower one.

A 'single-phase input to three-phase output' variable frequency drive would be ideal to run this three-phase motor off a single-phase supply.

Comment: Thank you, greybeard, for pointing out the error. I have duly edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR

No, it doesn't work like that and any electricians that told you it could are incompetent. You should probably buy a single phase 220 V motor and put that on your compressor. Based on your question you are not an electrician and you should really have one (maybe ideally HVAC company) come in and do this for you so you don't kill yourself. I'm serious. 220 V is dangerous and your running currents are more than enough to kill you.

## Long answer, or you are dead set on 3 phase

### 1 phase vs 3 phase

You can power one phase of your 3 phase motor on a single phase. A motor designed for 3 phases will not rotate with only one phase supplied.

What you need is a phase converter. This device takes single phase and gives you 3 phase.

### Power and voltage ratings

Based on your phase converter choice, you may have adjustable or fixed voltage. You need to verify that your phase converter can output to your motor nameplate specs.

### Master supply breaker

based on your power requirements and your phase converter choice, you will need to make sure you have an appropriately sized breaker and wiring from your main breaker to your phase converter, and from your phase converter to your 3 phase compressor.

You need an electrician (an actual one) to come in and do this for you).

Comment: Thank you for your response , I thought that a phase converter is what I needed , I am happy you verified that , and as far as being dead set on 3 phase ,no, it's just  the only motor I have currently that will pull my compressor and it was free . A 220 5 ho is around 350 bucks here . I am going to call about a phase converter and someone to install it possibly.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to connect your 220 VAC supply, L1 and L2, to two of the windings, T1 and T2 (connected for low voltage), and an AC run capacitor from L1 or L2 to T3. I have done this with a very small three phase motor, and it started and ran from about 50 VAC to 120 VAC. Although I have not tried it on a larger motor, there should be no problem doing the same on a 5 HP (3.75 kVA) motor. However, it should not be loaded any higher than 2.5 HP (1.87 kVA).

The rated running current should be about 9.82 A/phase and 127 volts on each winding to the (virtual) neutral, which is an impedance of 12.9 ohms. At 127 V and 60 Hz this would be a capacitance of 20.6 uF.

I'll try a simulation

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3urir.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Currents]

That's not a very good simulation, and the only way I got it close was a much larger capacitor. My hands-on experiment produced almost equal phase voltages, which indicates a pretty good three phase. An actual running induction motor will generate the third phase, and there are many examples of people who just get a larger three phase motor running on single phase, with the capacitor mostly to provide starting torque and a smoother waveform. A compressor likely will need a lot of start-up torque, so this passive (static) phase converter might not work in your application.

Here is an LTspice simulation showing how to get a pretty good three phase from single phase. This is at 480 VAC:

[image: 3 phase static converter]